# What is the maximum number of event source mappings per AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I cannot find this limitation listed anywhere in the AWS Documentation for maximum number of event sources to trigger one Lambda.

I have a Lambda which will be triggered by an indefinitely growing number of S3 Buckets. Obviously this will only work if the maximum number of buckets exceeds the maximum number of triggers. Is there a maximium? If so, what is it, and can it be increased?

Comment: could you go S3->SNS->Lambda ?

Comment: Yes I believe so. If the trigger limit is sufficient, I'd prefer it. If not, though, this does seem like a good solution.

Comment: Since S3 triggers are applied at individual bucket level, theoretically this should not be an issue (haven't tested though) - and the issue mentioned in @GregS's answer should be bypassable by customizing the Lambda's permission policy to use a wildcard `Resource` filter instead of an actual list of bucket names - which should be possible in most of the common cases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into a limit. I added **60 CloudWatch triggers** to a Lambda function and when I tried adding one more trigger, I got an error saying:

> "The final policy size (20643) is bigger than the limit (20480). (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PolicyLengthExceededException;"

Comment: I got a notification about this question viewers, but I took a look and realized I had never marked this correct. I assume this limit has not changed, so have some internet schmeckles. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably related to the auto-generated Lambda permission policy - which you can customize in most cases to bypass the limit (e.g. by using a wildcard `Resource` filter) - and not to the event sources themselves; hence @djcrabhat's answer should be the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

There's a paginated response to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ListEventSourceMappings.html , and since I can find no info on the lambda limits page, I bet there's no limit (or at least there's some huge number you don't have to practically worry about).

Answer (score 2):

This is still very high in search results, which led me here. I was able to create 6500 event source mappings for an MQ Event Source. The Web Console maxes out at 1000 displayed event source mappings. I did not verify that all 6500 event source mappings worked.